# Expanding nodes with Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am trying to make a graph that, when the page loads, expands all the nodes in the graph out from the root node like a tree, like the opposite of [this example](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/images-breadthfirst-layout/). The graph is directed with no cycles and a pre-defined root node.

Right now, I hide all the nodes on the graph. I then run a DFS from the root node. At each child node, I move it to the location of the parent node, and then want to run .animate() with its original position as the destination so that there is a smooth animation. As seen in the code, the .animate() function doesn't pause the rest of the program. Any advice?

```js
var cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'content': 'data(id)'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'width': 4,
        'line-color': '#ddd',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ddd',
      }),

  elements: {
    nodes: [
        { data: { id: 'a' } },
        { data: { id: 'b' } },
        { data: { id: 'c' } },
        { data: { id: 'd' } },
        { data: { id: 'e' } }
      ],

      edges: [
        { data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
        { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 3, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
        { data: { id: 'bc', weight: 5, source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
        { data: { id: 'cd', weight: 2, source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
      ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'breadthfirst',
    directed: true,
    padding: 10,
    roots: '#a',
  }
}); // cy init

var root_id = 'a'

//get root
var root = cy.$('#'+root_id)[0]

//empty collection
var collection = cy.collection()

//hide all nodes except root
cy.ready(function(event){
   collection = collection.add(cy.nodes('node[id!="'+root_id+'"]'))
   collection = collection.add(cy.nodes().connectedEdges());
   collection.style('visibility', 'hidden')
});


var visited_nodes = [root];
function dfs(node) {
  //visit node
  visited_nodes.push(node)
  
  //for each neighbor w ov f
  neighbors = cy.$('#'+node.id()).outgoers('edge')
  neighbors.forEach(function (next) { 
    var next_node = cy.$('#'+next.data().target)
    if (visited_nodes.indexOf(next_node) < 0){
      //visit each unvisited node
      //we will move the target node to the source node, then use .animate() to move the target node back to it's original location
      source_id = next.data('source')
      target_id = next.data('target')
      var node_to_move = cy.$('#' + next.data('target'))[0]
      
      //record the x and y coordinates to avoid messing around for objects. temporary.
      var start_position_x = cy.$('#' + next.data('source')).position().x
      var start_position_y = cy.$('#' + next.data('source')).position().y
      var end_position_x = cy.$('#' + next.data('target')).position().x
      var end_position_y = cy.$('#' + next.data('target')).position().y
      
      //move the target node to its start position
      node_to_move.position('x',start_position_x)
      node_to_move.position('y',start_position_y)
      node_to_move.style('visibility', 'visible')

      //then animate the target node moving to it's original position
      node_to_move.animate(
      {
        position: {end_position_x, end_position_y}
      },
      { 
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function(){
          node_to_move.style('visibility', 'visible')
          // if (e !== undefined){
          //   e.style('visibility', 'visible')
          // }
        }
      }) 

      //DOESNT WORK WITH THESE COMMENTED OUT, DOES WITH THEM COMMENTED IN/
      //I think this means it is a timing problem, with the dsf moving forward without the nodes getting moved
      // node_to_move.position('x',end_position_x)
      // node_to_move.position('y',end_position_y)
      
      dfs(next_node)      
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body { 
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#eat {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #c88;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This code is for demonstration purposes only.  You should not hotlink to Github, Rawgit, or files from the Cytoscape.js documentation in your production apps. -->
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
<title>Images</title>
<script src="cube/node_modules/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy"></div>
<!-- Load appplication code at the end to ensure DOM is loaded -->
<script src="expand.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran the animations at the same time.  Chain animations using promises, e.g. `node1.animation().play().promise().then( node2.animation().play.promise() ).then( ... )`

Comment: How would you chain .animate() within the dfs stack? You don't really have the list of nodes until the end, unless you're suggesting just doing dfs to get the order then using the chaining + promise method?

Comment: Chain the promises.  You can `.then()` anywhere.